# Gnome Commander won't start on 16.04

Tags: filemanager

I installed it, does nothing when I press the "Launch" in the shop window, and I can't add it to the launcher either. Ideas?

Any decent two-pane commander other than Midnight Commander or KDE-related software? (from what I've read so far, Gnomes run away from KDE/QT like rats from the flood. Not surprisingly since it's one UI library ported on top of another, but I guess I'll have no choice but to deal with it, unless the Gnomes come to my rescue with some solution/alternative :D ).

Comment: In terminal type `gnome-commander` and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/812104/edit) your question with the output.

Answer (score 1):

**[Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/)** is a very good one. However, I do not know if it is available in Ubuntu repositories. If it is not available, then here is how to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexx2000/doublecmd
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install doublecmd-gtk
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I have gnome-commander installed on Mandriva 10.0. I have found that it won't start when gvfs is trying to do something that it can't finish. In most cases it was process mount found as child process of gvfs-fuse-daemon. Killing the process mount enables gnome-commander to start.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment in the Ubuntu Software "app", Gnome Commander will work when installed from `sudo`, even though (for me, on 17.10), trying to install it from the Software "app" silently fails.

In the terminal, then,

```
 sudo apt install gnome-commander
```

and it *should* ... just work!

One glitch is that it doesn't seem to detect and display other media automatically. For example, looking for a USB memory stick, I need to navigate to `/media/user/...` to find the device. (The Software app comment mentioned something about "meld" in this connection, but that's beyond my understanding.)

At least this makes for a working installation of Gnome Commander for Ubuntu 17.10.